# Motorola Xoom Browser Specs

Tags: android, browser, tablet, motorola, mobile-browser

Does anyone know or have references for the browser used on Motorola Xoom..
I mean which browser, version, engine ,viewport,  etc...

Comment: Also as a follow-up question, are all the Android tablet browser's same in all respects or are there some minor differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be the standard Android webkit based brower, the screen res is 1280x800 I believe but Im not sure of the viewport size. So I cant be more help than that

Comment: Any references to Android tablet browser online ?

Answer (score 1):

Please download and use the emulator on android SDK

Refer : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html
This has the browser app available for testing